# How to load static files in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-settings

```
ingestion-dashboard/
├── apps
│   ├── adapter
│   ├── authentication
|   |__init__.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── assets
│   │        │-- css
│   │        │── img
│   │        │── scss
│   │        │── vendor
│   └── templates
│       ├── accounts
│       ├── home
│  
├── dashboard
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└───staticfiles
    ├── assets
         │── css
         │── img
         │── scss
         │── vendor
```

settings.py

```
CORE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) # ingestion-dashboard
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'apps/static'),
)
```

With this layout, django works fine with **local server** with proper loading of bootstraps and styles.
But when i ran this on kubernetes/nginx , the app is working fine but missing bootstraps, styles.

The `staticfiles` dir in `ingestion-dashboard/dashboard/staticfiles` is being populated by command `django-admin manage.py collectstatic`.

Any help is appreciated.

I have loaded styles as

```
<script src="/static/assets/vendor/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

works fine with local development.

Following are some configs:

```
Base_dir: /ingestion-dashboard
STATIC_ROOT: /ingestion-dashboard/staticfiles
STATICFILES_DIRS: ('/ingestion-dashboard/apps/static',)
```

When i tried to debug via `python manage.py findstatic css/volt.css --verbosity=2`

```
No matching file found for 'css/volt.css'.

Looking in the following locations:
  /opt/ingestion-dashboard2/ingestion-dashboard/apps/static
```

while `css/volt.css` is present at `apps/static/assets/css/volt.css`

Comment: Use [static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#static) template tag, ```{% load static %}``` then ```<script src="{% static assets/vendor/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js' %}" </script>```

Comment: Did same too , but it did not work

Comment: `when i ran this on kubernetes/nginx` with DEBUG=false?